# fullpage.js normal scroll after plugin

Tags: fullpage.js

I cant get the plugin to resume normal scroll after the set it is applied to.

I have the plugin applied to main tag:

```
$("main").fullpage({ sectionSelector: "> *");
```

after getting to the last section from main i want to be able to scroll the footer sections (normal no full screen ), but I cant get it working.

```
<body>
<main>
     <div class="title fp-auto-height"></div>
     <section>1</section>
     <section>2</section>
...
</main>
<footer>
     <section>1</section>
</footer>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not.

The most you can do is simulate that by using the fullpage.js option `scrollOverflow` and adding all your page content on the last section .

It will create an scrollbar as the one you can see in [this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).

Comment: Thanks, ill move the footer inside section to act as a single section as per your instructions :)